# unable to add custom js script in child theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i need to add a custom script in my child theme in wordpress.

This is the content of my child theme :

```
themes    
  |meteorite
    |style.css
  |meteorite-child
    |function.php
    |style.css
    |js
      |mngclk.js
```

my function.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}

wp_register_script( 'new-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/mngclk.js', 'jquery', "1", true);

wp_enqueue_script( 'new-script' );
```

I tried multiple change but i did not manage to inclute my custom js script

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper example

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Follow this link for more info

[enter link description here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: Style.css is ok, my problem is with the js file.
I already read this link but there was no information for javascript

Comment: i think the third parameter for wp_register_script function, you used just 'jquery', you should use an array like this array('jquery')

Answer (score 0):

add below function in child theme function.php

```
function add_child_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0' );
    /* wp_enqueue_script( 'new-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/mngclk.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true ); */
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_child_theme_scripts' );
```

add below function in child theme function.php file

```
<?php
function myscript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function mngClk(str){
        document.location.href= decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(str)));
    }
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'myscript' );
?>
```

Comment: i tried this but i still can't view js file loaded in the head. And when i try to call the function inside the js. it still say Uncaught ReferenceError: mngClk is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick ((index):318)

Comment: please provide us website link and child theme file path. because your js is in child theme js folder. so put the js in child theme/js/mngclk.js

Comment: the website is [link]tuyauarrosage.fr
i tried to set : https://tuyauarrosage.fr/wp-content/themes/meteorite-child/js/mngclk.js directly in function.php but this doesn't fix the problem despite i can access the file correctly using web browser.

Comment: same problem. (the solution you provided is actualy uploaded)
I'm gonna guess if the problem is not coming from elsewere...

Comment: i copy paste the whole code you gave to me. the 2 blocks, first about style css and second about javascript. still the problem.
i'll check it on an other wordpress without any plugin to detect if there is something missing.